# HTML page is not loading in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure, spring-security, azure-active-directory

I've used following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory

In this I was able to authorize, but when the page opens, instead of the HTML page I want to show, I see this:

[image: browser image]

But in controller I'm calling `newhome.html`:

[image: controller image]

Controller code:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_group1')"
              + "|| hasRole('ROLE_group2')"
              + "|| hasRole('ROLE_group3')")
public String onInit(
        Model model, 
        @RequestHeader(value = "LIST", defaultValue = "group1") String groups,
        @RequestHeader(value = "USERNAME", defaultValue = "shubham") String userName) {
    
    if (userName != null && !userName.isEmpty()) {
        if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
            LOG.trace("<< onInit() Navigating to Home");
            return "newhome";
        } else {
            LOG.trace("<< onInit() Navigating to Error");
            return "error";
        }
    }                
}
```

Here `newhome` and `error` are HTML pages.

It was working fine before adding Azure AD authentication, but now after implementing, it is just showing the of the HTML page.

I would be thankfull for any help.

Comment: This really doesn’t provide any info - what exactly is it that doesn’t work as expected and exactly you need help with? Also don’t post links, post actual code

Comment: @JAsgarov i've updated some code from controller

Comment: Shubham, I've fixed the code formatting but it doesn't look like the same code as from your screenshot. Can you please verify that the code from your question is the same as the code from you app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using @ResponseBody you are returning a simple String. I’m assuming you want to return a template page called “newhome” instead. Just remove the @ResponseBody and it should work